File "<COMObject GetThumbsCrypto.GetCertificateThumbs>" error loading Pkcs11Interop, Version=4.1.1.0
I am writing .dll for getting thumbprint string from hardware token, using packages:
packages.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Aktiv.RutokenPkcs11Interop" version="2.0.11" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Pkcs11Interop" version="4.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>

App.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Pkcs11Interop" publicKeyToken="c10e9c2d8c006d2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>

When i run code directly in VS2022, it works fine, but when i build it and try to call from python VS Code - it dumps with error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...

print(com_object.GetThumbsString())   File "", line 3, in GetThumbsString
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Error.', (0, 'GetThumbsCrypto',
'Failed to load file or assembly "Pkcs11Interop, Version=4.1.1.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c10e9c2d8c006d2a" or one of its
dependencies. The specified file cannot be found.', None, 0,
-2147024894), None)

Python
import win32com.client

def main():
    com_object = win32com.client.Dispatch("GetThumbsCrypto.GetCertificateThumbs")
    print(com_object.GetThumbsString())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

C#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Net.Pkcs11Interop.Common;
using Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI;
using RutokenPkcs11Interop;
using RutokenPkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GetThumbsCrypto
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [Guid("0EA9F9D3-7AE9-4816-8717-E6F0FAF67887")]
    public interface IGetCertificateThumbs
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        string GetThumbsString();
        [DispId(2)]
        string TestSub();  
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("8DD66953-3247-4206-B37E-3C3F7B5850F6"),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class GetCertificateThumbs : IGetCertificateThumbs
    {
        // Certificate search template
        static readonly List<ObjectAttribute> CertificateAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>
        {
            // Certificate object
            new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_CERTIFICATE),
            // Certificate is a token object
            new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true),
            // Certificate is accessible without authentication
            new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_PRIVATE, false),
            // Certificate type is X.509
            new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, CKC.CKC_X_509),
        };
       
        public string TestSub()
        {
            return "Test is ok";
        }
        
        public string GetThumbsString()
        {
            string res = "";
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Library initialization");
                using (var pkcs11 = new Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI.Pkcs11(Settings.RutokenEcpDllDefaultPath, AppType.MultiThreaded))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Checking tokens available");
                    Slot slot = GetUsableSlot(pkcs11);
                    Console.WriteLine("Opening RW session");
                    using (Session session = slot.OpenSession(SessionType.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Getting information...");
                            Console.WriteLine(" Getting certificates...");
                            List<ObjectAttribute> publicKeyAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
                            publicKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_CERTIFICATE));
                            publicKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true));
                            publicKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, CKC.CKC_X_509));
                            var certificates = session.FindAllObjects(CertificateAttributes);
                            Errors.Check(" Certificates not found", certificates != null);
                            Errors.Check(" Certificates not found", certificates.Any());
                            List<string> thumbprints = new List<string>();                          
                            foreach (var certificateObject in certificates)
                            {                                
                                byte[] certificateData = session.GetAttributeValue(certificateObject, new List<CKA> { CKA.CKA_VALUE })[0].GetValueAsByteArray();
                                byte[] thumbprintBytes;
                                using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
                                {
                                    thumbprintBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(certificateData);
                                }
                                string thumbprint = BitConverter.ToString(thumbprintBytes).Replace("-", "");
                                thumbprints.Add(thumbprint);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("Thumbprints of found certificates:");
                            foreach (var thumbprint in thumbprints)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(thumbprint);
                                res = string.Join("$", thumbprints);
                            }                            
                            string certificateInfo = session.GetCertificateInfoText(certificates[0]);
                            Errors.Check(" Certificate info not found", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(certificateInfo));
                            Console.WriteLine(certificateInfo);
                            Console.WriteLine("Information has been acquired successfully");
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            session.Logout();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Pkcs11Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Operation failed [Method: {ex.Method}, RV: {ex.RV}]");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Operation failed [Message: {ex.Message}]");
            }
            return res;
        }
        
        public static Slot GetUsableSlot(Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI.Pkcs11 pkcs11)
        {
            List<Slot> slots = pkcs11.GetSlotList(SlotsType.WithTokenPresent);
            if (slots == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("No available slots");
            if (slots.Count <= 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No available slots");
            Slot slot = slots[0];
            return slot;
        }
    }
    
    public static class Errors
    {
        public static void Check(string errorMessage, bool condition)
        {
            if (!condition)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
        }
    }
}


I have tried to call TestSub() from com using python - it works fine.
I have reinstalled nuget packages.
I have changed target platform to 4.7.2 and then back to 4.5 - I don't know why.

Changed NuGet package Pkcs11Interop from 4.1.2 to 4.1.1.
